# Sort a list of tuples by the order of another list in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I have a list of tuples:

```
l1 = [(2, "text1"), (5, "text3"), (7, "text2")]
```

and another list of strings:

```
l2 = ["text1", "text2", "text3"]
```

I want to sort l1 by the order of l2 so that l1 will be:

```
[(2, "text1"), (7, "text2"), (5, "text3")]
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l1.sort(key=lambda x: l2.index(x[1]))
```